# Selecting a Range in a Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

To select text as heading I use this:

```
Dim rng As MsWord.Range = oDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
```

How to select all other text in document - from second line/paragraph in document till the end of document

I tried:

```
Dim startLocation As Object = oDoc.Sentences(2).Start
Dim endLocation As Object = oDoc.Sentences(2).End
rng = oDoc.Range(Start:=startLocation, End:=endLocation)
```

but problem is how to define end number. How to select all text from second line to end? If uploaded documents would be with different lenght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `oDoc.Range.End` like:

`oDoc.Range(oDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.Start, oDoc.Range.End).Select`

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to figure this out for two days. This is a similar syntax to selecting a range of cells in an Excel worksheet. 